# gradient vs derivative: defintions of

Tags: derivative, gradient

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient):

> In mathematics, the gradient is a multi-variable generalization of the
>   derivative. Like the derivative, the gradient represents the slope of
>   the tangent of the graph of the function. More precisely, the gradient
>   points in the direction of the greatest rate of increase of the
>   function, and its magnitude is the slope of the graph in that
>   direction.

If I understand it correctly, this means that the gradient points into the direction of the function to increase the fastest.

But derivative can also be negative, which means that the function is decreasing. So, if gradient and derivative are equal, is the wikipedia statement about "direction of the greatest rate of increase of the function" is wrong, because it can also point to the greatest rate of decrease actually=

Comment: Your quotation refers to a "multi-variable generalization." Thus, you are asking about the gradient *as a kind of vector.*  In what sense can a *vector* can be "negative" or "positive"?

Comment: I see what you mean but why then the gradient points into the direction of the greatest "increase" and not greatest "decrease" ?

Comment: Review the definition.  (There are many, so use whichever one you prefer.)